# Alternatives to PCA with orthogonal datasets?

Tags: pca, orthogonal

http://blog.audio-tk.com/2008/02/04/dimensionality-reduction-principal-components-analysis/

"It is obvious that PCA does not respect the manifold structure. One has to use 3 dimensions to describe this manifold, thus no compression can be achieved at all. Besides, projecting in this 3D space does not project on the manifold : another regularization term must be added so that the “reduced” space is probabilized. This is where Maximum A Posteriori (or the modified Mean-Shift algorithm from Vik et al.) comes into the game."

Alternatives to PCA with orthogonal datasets? i.e. swiss roll?

Comment: What is an orthogonal data set to you? A Swiss roll does not seem orthogonal to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find very interesting Self Organizing Maps. In the case of your Swiss Roll, you can obtain a mapping to 2d. Algorithm is explained in ESL .

Comment: What is the ESL?

Comment: Elements of Statistical Learning book by Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman. (chapter 14.4)